# Azure maps layers are getting on top of each other

Tags: azure-maps

I'm using azure map.

What's happening is that I have 2 layers. A layer that have Circles and a layer with polygons.

I have a functionality in which a popup appear when I click on a specific circle.

The issue occur when I add the polygon layer after the circle layer.

It's like the polygon layer is being drawn on top of the circle layer. In which it prevent the popup from appearing when clicking on the circle.

Here's how I'm adding the polygon layer:

```
showFetchedResultOnMap(facilities) {
 const self = this;
 if (facilities && facilities.length > 0) {
  self.cleanRestrictionLayer();
  //Create a data source and add it to the map.
  self.datasource = new atlas.source.DataSource();

  self.map.sources.add(self.datasource);
  //Add a data set to the data source. 

  self.CleanMap();
  //Create a data source and add it to the map.
  var datasource = new atlas.source.DataSource();
  self.map.sources.add(datasource);
  self.map.imageSprite.add(self.chosenCategory, 'assets/svg/' + self.chosenCategory + '.svg')
    .then(function () {
      facilities.forEach(cat => {
        datasource.add(new atlas.data.Feature(new atlas.data.Point([cat.longitude, cat.latitude])));
      });

      //Add a layer for rendering point data as symbols.
      self.map.layers.add(new atlas.layer.SymbolLayer(datasource, self.chosenCategory, {
        iconOptions: {
          //Pass in the id of the custom icon that was loaded into the map resources.
          image: self.chosenCategory,

          //Optionally scale the size of the icon.
          size: 0.1
        }
      }));
    });
}
}
```

Anyone have an Idea about how I can fix this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not seeing a polygon layer in the code you provided. That said, when you add layers to the map, the order in which you add them is the z-index by default. Last one added goes on top. That said, when adding the layer using the map.layers.add function, there is a second parameter you can add in which can be another layer or layer id. When this is specified the layer you are adding will be inserted below that second specified layer. Here is the doc on this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-control/atlas.layermanager?view=azure-maps-typescript-latest#add-layer---layer----string---layer-

Here is a short example:

```
map.layers.add(new atlas.layers.BubbleLayer(datasource, 'myBubbles'));

map.layers.add(new atlas.layers.PolygonLayer(datasource, 'myPolygons'), 'myBubbles');
```

Comment: So in the example you've provided, the Bubble layer will be on top of Polygon Layer?

Comment: One other question, what will happen If the provided `LayerId` does not exist? Would the application crash?

Comment: Yes, the bubble layer will appear above the polygon layer. If the layer id does not exist, the layer would be added to the top.